# How to apply style to delimited pipe used in a string using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, regex

I want to style delimited `|` used in a string , so i have used regex but its adding `span` tag into the message its not applying styles. Any idea how to achieve this task using Angularjs approach ?

ctrl.js

```
var data = "[2017-07-12T12:38:36-04:00]|zldssd255|info|<n/a>|[infra.actorRouter] Processing message from topic UEQ: 216014da-b849-4a1d-8232-3629e58338ce { partition: 0, offset: 12081530 }"

$scope.event = [];
var message = data.replace(/\|/g, '<span class="pipe">|</span>');
$scope.event.push({
    value: message
});
```

main.css

```
.pipe {
    width: 1em;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a **runnable** [mcve]. Note you can't use `{{}}` or `ng-bind` to insert html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that this question requires an angular approach. You can do this using CSS.

Your markup:

```
<div id="pipe"></div>
```

Your CSS:

```
#pipe:before {
  width: 1em;
  color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  content: '/';
}
```

Comment: we are adding span dynamically there is no `span` that is part of DOM so i am replacing string using regex and added pipe class to `span` so it can style delimited. what is `div` in your case ?

Comment: It doesn't matter whether it's being added dynamically or not. Just ignore the markup in this case, and use this CSS class.   You also need to remove the actual pipe from the span you're adding.

Comment: does not make sense to me may be i am missing something if you dont have markup where you specifying ID

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with AngularJS.
Your CSS is being applied, it's just that the HTML is rendered incorrectly because of your `<n/a>`:

```
<body>
    [2017-07-12T12:38:36-04:00]<span class="pipe">|</span>zldssd255<span class="pipe">|</span>info<span class="pipe">|</span>
    <n a=""><span class="pipe">|</span>[infra.actorRouter] Processing message from topic UEQ: 216014da-b849-4a1d-8232-3629e58338ce { partition: 0, offset: 12081530 }</n>
</body>
```

You'll have to escape those; use `&lt;` and `&gt;` or something similar in your message.

Comment: `n/a` means value is not available in the string , some logs are coming with value without `n/a` but i see same problem

Comment: I know thats why i asked for solution message format can not be change

Comment: In that case you need to encode it. See [here](https://www.w3schools.com/HTML/html_entities.asp) for an example list, and you could write an encoder/decoder function to alter the string to display before you try to send it.